# Return binary as string, NOT convert or cast

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, types

Is there a simple way (like convert or cast) to return a binary field as a string without actually converting it or casting it?

The data I want looks like this in the database:

```
0x24FC40460F58D64394A06684E9749F30
```

When using convert(varchar(max), binary_field), it comes back like this:

```
$ü@FXÖC” f„étŸ0
```

cast(binary_field as varchar(max)) had the same results.

I'm trying to modify a datasource in an old vb.net application, so I want it to be a string like the existing values, but still look like the original data.  I don't *have* to do it in the query, but I'd like to if possible to avoid modifying the old vb code too much.

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT strName, strDesc, binUUID
  FROM MyTableName
  where intFamily = '1234'
  order by strName
```

Alternatively, if I do cast/convert it, would it be safe to compare "$ü@FXÖC” f„étŸ0" stored as a string at a later time to another value gathered in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in function to generate hex strings from binary values

```
SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexstr (0x24FC40460F58D64394A06684E9749F30)
```

Comment: A+++ answer, would use again :D

<3 for simplicity